mariadb how to split string by delimiter into result set in a stored function
I'm trying to create a split function that I can call in my stored procedures, I know there is a function SUBSTRING_INDEX, I'm trying to return either a temporary table or a JSON array and failing.   I don't have much to show:
BEGIN
#Splits a subject text "strSubject" using the supplied "strPattern"
#The results are returned in the temporary table tbl_split_results
 RETURN SUBSTRING_INDEX(strSubject, strPattern, 9999);
END

Example of call:
SELECT split("Simon\r\nSusan\r\nLewis\r\nJordan\r\nOliver\r\n", "\r\n");

This just returns a single string with the delimiter "\r\n" removed, what I want is a row for each item.  The version of MariaDB is 11.5 (x64) running on Windows 10.0.19045.4780.
[Edit] so far, but still errors, not very helpful errors either, code:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `split`(
    `ttxtSubject` TINYTEXT,
    `ttxtPattern` TINYTEXT
)
RETURNS JSON
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'splits string by pattern'
BEGIN
#Splits a subject text "ttxtSubject" using the supplied "ttxtPattern"
#The results are returned in the temporary table tbl_split_results
    DECLARE intItr INT;
    #DECLARE jsonArray JSON;
    DECLARE ttxtResult TINYTEXT;
    SET intItr = 1;
    #SET jsonArray = Json_Make_Array();
    REPEAT
        SET ttxtResult = SUBSTRING_INDEX(ttxtSubject, ttxtPattern, intItr);
        IF ttxtResult THEN
            #Json_Array_Add(jsonArray, ttxtResult);
            SET intItr = intItr + 1;
        END IF;
    UNTIL NOT ttxtResult; 
    #RETURN jsonArray;
    RETURN NULL;
END

I've commented out several lines to try and debug, hasn't helped, the error shown when I try to save the function:
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOOP`forLoop`;
RETURN jsonArray;
END' at line 23

I've edited the post several times in an effort to fix, with various bits commented out, it still gives the same error.
Another edit have progressed a little:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `split`(
    `ttxtSubject` TINYTEXT,
    `ttxtPattern` TINYTEXT
)
RETURNS longtext CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'splits string by pattern'
BEGIN
#Splits a subject text "ttxtSubject" using the supplied "ttxtPattern"
#The results are returned in the temporary table tbl_split_results
    DECLARE jsonArray JSON;
    DECLARE ttxtResult TINYTEXT;
    SET jsonArray = Json_Make_Array();
    forLoop:FOR intItr IN 1..9999
    DO
        SET ttxtResult = SUBSTRING_INDEX(ttxtSubject, ttxtPattern, intItr);
        IF NOT ttxtResult THEN
            LEAVE forLoop;
        END IF;
        SET jsonArray = JSON_ARRAY(jsonArray, ttxtResult);
        SET intItr = intItr + 1;
    END FOR forLoop;
    RETURN jsonArray;
END

But event though I'm using MariaDB 11.8, I get:
SQL Error (1305): FUNCTION dbname.Json_Make_Array does not exist

So I changed code back to:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `split`(
    `ttxtSubject` TINYTEXT,
    `ttxtPattern` TINYTEXT
)
RETURNS longtext CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'splits string by pattern'
BEGIN
#Splits a subject text "ttxtSubject" using the supplied "ttxtPattern"
#The results are returned in the temporary table tbl_split_results
    DECLARE jsonArray JSON;
    DECLARE ttxtResult TINYTEXT;
    SET jsonArray = JSON_ARRAY();
    forLoop:FOR intItr IN 1..9999
    DO
        SET ttxtResult = SUBSTRING_INDEX(ttxtSubject, ttxtPattern, intItr);
        IF NOT ttxtResult THEN
            LEAVE forLoop;
        END IF;
        SET jsonArray = JSON_ARRAY(jsonArray, ttxtResult);
        SET intItr = intItr + 1;
    END FOR forLoop;
    RETURN jsonArray;
END

However when I test with:
SELECT split("Simon\r\nSusan\r\nLewis\r\nJordan\r\nOliver\r\n", "\r\n");

The result shown is:
[]


what does select version(); show?

@ysth, 11.5.2-MariaDB

IF NOT ttxtResult THEN will not work with character data

In the end I made constructed the JSON array myself:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `split`(
    `mtxtSubject` MEDIUMTEXT,
    `mtxtPattern` MEDIUMTEXT
)
RETURNS mediumtext CHARSET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'splits string by pattern'
BEGIN
#Splits a subject text "mtxtSubject" using the supplied "mtxtPattern"
#The results are returned in the temporary table tbl_split_results
    DECLARE intItem, intItemLen, intPatternLen, intSkipLen INT; 
    DECLARE mtxtResult MEDIUMTEXT DEFAULT '[';
    DECLARE mtxtNew MEDIUMTEXT;
    SET intItem = 0;
    Set intPatternLen = LENGTH(mtxtPattern);
    txtLoop:LOOP
        IF LENGTH(mtxtSubject) = 0 THEN
            LEAVE txtLoop;
        END IF;
    #Search for the first match using the passed delimiter
        SET mtxtNew = SUBSTRING_INDEX(mtxtSubject, mtxtPattern, 1);
        SET intItemLen = LENGTH(mtxtNew);
        IF intItemLen = 0 THEN
    #Nothing taken, abort search        
            LEAVE txtLoop;
        END IF;
    #Work out total length to skip in subject mater 
        SET intSkipLen = intItemLen + intPatternLen;
    #Append the new item to the results
        SET mtxtResult = CONCAT(mtxtResult
                        ,IF(LENGTH(mtxtResult) > 1, ',', ''), "'", mtxtNew, "'");       
    #Skip over the content and delimiter just extracted 
        SET mtxtSubject = SUBSTRING(mtxtSubject, intSkipLen + 1);
    #Increment item number
        SET intItem = intItem + 1;
    END LOOP txtLoop;
    SET mtxtResult = CONCAT(mtxtResult, ']');
    RETURN mtxtResult;
END

Example:
SELECT split("Simon\r\nPlatten", "\r\n");

Result:
['Simon','Platten']


Note that this will break horribly if there is a quote character within the text. Also, you're not outputting JSON – JSON does not quote strings with single quotes.

You are missing the END IF from your IF clause.
You can use something like this:
create function split(
ttxtSubject tinytext,
ttxtPattern tinytext
)
returns json
comment 'splits string by pattern'
begin
-- Splits a subject text "ttxtSubject" using the supplied "ttxtPattern"
-- The result is returned as a JSON array
declare ind int default 1;
declare done int default 0;
declare item tinytext;
declare jsonArray tinytext;

while not done do
  set item = substring_index(substring_index(ttxtsubject, ttxtpattern, ind), ttxtpattern, -1);

  if (item = '') then
    set done = 1;
  else
    if (jsonArray is null) then
      set jsonArray = json_array(item);
    else
      set jsonArray = json_array_append(jsonArray, '$', item);
    end if;
  end if;

  set ind = ind + 1;
end while;

return jsonArray;
end


Thank you, I added that, same result same message.

SET @arg := 'Simon\r\nSusan\r\nLewis\r\nJordan\r\nOliver\r\n',
    @delim := '\r\n';

SELECT value
FROM JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@arg, @delim, '","'), '"]'),
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (value VARCHAR(128) PATH '$')
                ) jsontable
HAVING value <> '';




value




Simon


Susan


Lewis


Jordan


Oliver



fiddle
If the string may contain " or \ then add REPLACE which doubles them.
If you need in JSON array strictly then apply JSON_ARRAY().
If you need in JSON array and do not need to remove empty values then single CONCAT(REPLACE) is enough. Or even REGEXP_REPLACE.
